# How can I tell when a font was installed?

Tags: fonts, windows-server-2008-r2, date-modified

On Windows Server 2008 RC2, is there a reliable way to determine when a specific font was installed? I do know for sure that it was installed manually, i.e. didn't come pre-bundled with the system.

Things I've tried:

- Looking at the Registry entry in `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts`. Unfortunately, I don't think there's any way of figuring out when an entry was created
- Looking at the .ttf file's "Properties" window. There are "Created" and "Modified" timestamps, but I don't know if this is when the font was installed on the system, or when the .ttf file was originally created.

For context, I'm trying to use the font in an ASP.NET application, and need to make sure that the font was installed [*before* the most recent reboot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2964117) (otherwise I'll have to restart the server again, which is an undesirable solution).

Comment: Unless you had file auditing turned on and configured when it was added, I don't think you'll be able to know.

Comment: You could obtain the last write time of the registry key. That might not be accurate enough in case other fonts were installed as well, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Created" is when the file was created on that particular filesystem; e.g. if you just copied a year old file from another drive, or extracted from an old archive, the new copy will be "created" today. As far as I know, there is no function to "backdate" this timestamp. So this is the one you're looking for.

"Modified" is when the file was changed anywhere. This timestamp is generally copied around along with the file – even things like archivers, web browsers, and FTP often preserve it. So, very often, it reflects the original file modification time. (On the other hand, it's easy to accidentally reset it...)

Comment: fyi: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724290(v=vs.85).aspx

and i think windows keeps the creation time IF the fs where the file in question originates from supports create-time as well or the tool which copies over the file to the destination.

Comment: i tested several methods of creating a file (copy, from winscp, from 7z, by creating a hardlink): the create-time was always set to the current time. so, the things i thought in my previous comment are false. create-time is always set to what the current time actually is (allthough the winapi allows the change of the create-time). @grawity's answer is correct.

Comment: The file in question has a "Modified" time stamp that pre-dates the "Created" time stamp. I guess that makes sense if the "Modified" "generally copied around along with the file", it just seems kind of counter-intuitive.